# Django Model - Inherited Fields (Sorta ?)

Tags: django, model

how can I structure the RegisteredSubscriber model to achieve the functionality described in the pseudo code below?

I guess I could have implemented a function for each field, but that doesn't seem correct and is kinda labourous. Thoughts?

```
 61 class RegisteredSubscriber(Subscriber):
 62     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 63     first_name = self.user.first_name
 64     last_name = self.user.last_name
 65     email = self.user.email
 66
 67 class AnonymousSubscriber(Subscriber):
 68     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 69     last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
 70     email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
```

---

Okay, this is achieves the functionality I wanted, but I'm sure its not proper. Thoughts? What would be the formal method, have I made a design error?

```
 59 class RegisteredSubscriber(Subscriber):
 60     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)
 61     first_name = 'candy'
 62     last_name = 'candy'
 63     email = 'candy'
 64
 65     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
 66         super(RegisteredSubscriber, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 67         
 68         if self.id:
 69             self.first_name = self.user.first_name
 70             self.last_name = self.user.last_name
 71             self.email = self.user.email
 72
 73     def __unicode__(self):
 74         return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: But why not to take first_name, last_name, ... from the *user* field you already have in RegisteredSubscriber?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `ForeignKey` relationship to the `User`, I don't understand the need to have `first_name, last_name, email` fields in the `RegisteredSubscriber` model, unless i'm missing something. If you want to access the `first_name` etc fields using the `RegisteredSubscriber` instance the `ForeignKey` relation ship allows you to use `__`. 
eg: `user__first_name`.

Comment: The reason is because, lets say I have a subscriber object sub.

I'd like access the first_name in both cases using sub.first_name, instead of having sub.user__firstname or sub.user.first_name if the sub is a RegisteredSubscriber.

Comment: do you want to store a copy of the user's `first_name` etc in the `RegisteredSubscriber` table or just access it like `sub.first_name`?